# Updating state of Sibling/Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a sidenav that keeps track of what's open through an openPath state. On click of another panel, it collapses the previous and opens the new panel clicked. In my index page body, I want to have buttons that on click update the path to the path of those particular panels on the sidenav. So setting state in my sidenav works perfectly. I just also want to be able to ALSO update this openPath from index Page on click of a button.

So my sidenav is like this

```
   class Sidebar extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
      const openPath = window.history.state.openPath
      this.state = {
        openPath: openPath || null
      };

      }

    handleOpen = path => {
        this.setState({openPath: path});

      };
```

My sidenav is in my layout component so it's like

```
LayOut (props) {
<SideNav/>
<Other Components/>
}
```

And my index page calls the layout component and the layout wraps the buttons.  I want to update the sidebar openPath on click of one of these buttons from the Index page component.

```
Class Index {
<LayOut>
<Button1/>
<Button2/>
</Layout>
}
```

Comment: Is using react router an option? Accessing window.history looks like you can use react router to handle routing for `openPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is

1. Create a React context.
2. Expose a method to update `openPath` from context provider (in Sidebar), say (updateOpenPath).
3. Consume the context by associating `updateOpenPath` to button clicks

Comment: Thank you! That worked the best for me and I also learnt React Context API now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you should be passing data down to child components as `props`.

In your case, this might require you *hoisting the state* to the parent component of the `SideNav` component. Once you do this, siblings can share the same values as props. This is a common paradigm in React development and is [described in the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 0):

Keep your state in index component and pass down the update handler as a prop. There by every time, when a button is click from side bar even the layout rerenders

Comment: @AnneJoday you can probably try something like, the layout is the top level component and the side bar is present there, and the routing config in the right pane. I will try to see if I have a working solution for this